# Google Maps Geocode API only works via browser

Tags: php, google-maps, file-get-contents, google-geocoder

I try to retrieve the latitude and longitude data by postalcode/zipcode.

This is the URL that I'm using:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=9462AA

The url returns JSON data (including latitude/longitude values) once I open it via the browser.

But when I call the exact same URL via the PHP `file_get_contents` method, it returns 'ZERO_RESULTS'.

```
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=9462AA';
$geocode = file_get_contents($url);

echo $url; 
echo $geocode;
```

This prints the following result:

URL: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=9462AA

Geocode:

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: i get zero results from url, perhaps you have cookies sessions with the credentials. -try an alterntive browser

Comment: @Dagon Hi, tried in Chrome, IE, Firefox. All three are returning JSON data... Cleared cookies/sessions as well.

Comment: odd i get zero results on every browser. i still think you have been authenticated somehow already hence the results.

Comment: @Dagon Here is an Gyazo: https://gyazo.com/326c1fca7c139fac744d96fcd31e847b

Comment: zero results here too as given, but using 946 2AA with the space (lucky guess) worked a treat

Comment: ^^^^ same, space made it work

Comment: @Dagon well... I'm confused now, lol

Comment: Not the same results with the space though, according to that screenshot.

Comment: im thinking its checking what country we are in based on out IP and using the local postcode to look it up, as we are all in different country's we get diff results ? 2 countries could have the same postcode for diffident places?

Comment: I get the right results by removing "AA" completely. Could they not be real "A" but some other unicode weirdness ? A country check would still work with php if it's on localhost (for the op).

Comment: Mhm putting a space after the digits, between 9462 and AA, works with file_get_contents. Conclusion: Via the browser you can call with or without a space or '+' between digits and characters, and in PHP you need to seperate those with a space or '+'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a space after the postalcode digits, in my case between 9462 and AA, works with `file_get_contents`.

Conclusion: via the browser you can do an API call with or without a space or '+' between the digits and characters, and in PHP you need to seperate those with a space or '+'.

The final URL became:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=9462+AA