# file_get_contents & curl returns empty string for google trends

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

i tried getting the contents of this url

http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=ex%20machina&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3

with file_get_contents and curl but it returns nothing, however when i went directly to the link it shows the content so its not a problem with api limits etc.

It worked once, but not after subsequent calls

heres the curl method i used

```
 function get_data($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        //$timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: How do you use get_data? It works fine for me if I use 'echo get_data("URL_HERE");'

Comment: `file_get_contents(url)` is working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the Google Maps Geocoder API in combination with `file_get_contents`, you can find the solution here:

[Google Maps Geocode API only works via browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909037/google-maps-geocode-api-only-works-via-browser)

Try this url:
http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=ex+machina&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3